# Open Stream on picked Uri without using StartActivity

Tags: android, file, android-activity, xamarin.forms, uri

This code is from the Android side of a Xamarin.Forms project. I have the uri of a file successfully picked and a stream created from the uri. At a later time I want to read the stream from the uri again, by-passing all of the picking stuff and just going straight for the stream. The code below works BUT the StartActivity(intent) opens a pick screen where the file is located which is undesired.

If I understand correctly you can only gain permission for a "content://" uri in the context of the activity. So the question is, is there a way to create a usable activity that does not open a screen but will allow permission to read the file or get the stream? I'd even settle for a different strategy for getting the stream off a "content://" uri.

```
public async Task<System.IO.Stream> OpenFile(StorageProfile FileToOpen)
    {
        if (IOUtil.IsMediaStore(FileToOpen.Path))   //If Path starts with "content"
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(FileToOpen.Path);
            var mime = IOUtil.GetMimeType(uri.ToString());

            var intent = new Intent();

            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
            intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mime);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            this.context.StartActivity(intent);

            var contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(FileToOpen.Path);
            System.IO.Stream fileStream = Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(contentUri);
            return fileStream;
        }
        else      //There is a real path to work with
        {
            System.IO.Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileToOpen.Path);
            return fileStream;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "The code below works BUT the StartActivity(intent) opens a pick screen where the file is located which is undesired" -- then delete it. It is not doing anything useful. For example, it is not giving you any rights for the `Uri` that you do not already have, unless Xamarin is doing some seriously weird stuff to the Android SDK.

Comment: If just the StartActivity line is commented out, the following error occurs which has been a big wall to resolving this issue. This error happens with any "content://" uri. App has ReadExternalStorage priv.

Java.Lang.SecurityException
  Message=Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.apps.docs.storagebackend.StorageBackendContentProvider uri content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DtEuwAnry2ndjYGUkS32f4shX1HSY9rRn6eKHL1vTx8y9stV9Lg%3D%3D from pid=7449, uid=10416 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Comment: @MikeN. Hi , Having a look at [Writing Responsive Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/writing-responsive-apps) . Maybe you need a thread to do not completed task when navigation .